# R index variable shrunk to number of unique groups

Tags: r, indexing, shrink

I have a data frame, *dat*, with 214 rows of data. Each row contains these variables: *Species* and *Mode* either *red* or *green*. I have sorted the data by *Species*. I would like to create a numeric index variable where if mode is *red* then `index = 0` else `index = 1`.

Further, the index can only be as long as the unique number of species that exist (N=72), such that, if there are 5 of *speciesA, red* and 7 of *speciesB, green* that is a *red* species, then `row 1 = 0` and `row 2 = 1`and so on. Here is the code I have tried so far:

```
index <- for (q in 1:unique(species)) {
      ifelse(mode[q]=='red',0,1)
}
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone who helped me via pm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
index <- as.numeric(factor(my_dataframe$mode))
```

A factor, under the hood, is stored as an integer.  So the conversion from factor to numeric index is 1 to 1.